# 1-form on $S^n$ with non-degenerate differential.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

How it can be solved?
Whether there is a $1$-differential form $w$ on $S^n$, such that $dw$ is non-degenerate on $T_aS^n$ for each $a \in S^n$?

Comment: @StevenGubkin I'm not sure that works, nothing keeps $w$ from vanishing. We only require $dw$ to never vanish.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, there is no such $\omega$ for any $n$.

To see this, assume for a contradiction that such an $\omega$ exists.  Then, since $d^2 \omega= 0$, $d\omega$ is closed, and it is non-degenerate by assumption.  This implies $(S^n, d\omega)$ is a [symplectic manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold).

Much is known about symplectic manifolds.  For example, it immediately follows that $n$ is even.  Further, the $n$-form $(d\omega)^\frac{n}{2}$ is known be a volume form.  In particular, $[d\omega]^\frac{n}{2} \neq 0\in H_{\text{de Rham}}^n(S^n)$.

Of course, this is absurd, because, by definition of de Rham cohomology, $[d\omega] = 0 \in H_{\text{de Rham}}^2(S^n)$.  This contradiction shows that no such $\omega$ exists.

Comment: I know nothing about symplectic manifolds except for the definition. Can u give me some reference for these facts, please?

Comment: Nice. 9 more to go

Comment: All these facts are easy to prove, thanks. I don't need references more.

Comment: @Dirk:  Ok, great.  (In fact, they are true on the vector space level - no need to use the "differential" part to prove them.

Comment: @Olivier:  9 more what?

Comment: 9 more caracters.